# Exporting map with transparent background to png or jpg?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, transparency-opacity, arcgis-10.5, jpg, png

Is there any possible way to export a map from Arcmap 10.5 without the white background?

I need to insert the map in a dashboard with blue background and i only need the outline of the layer not the white background.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Answer (score 0):

From the help on [ExportToPNG](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/exporttopng.htm):

> PNG files also have the ability to define a transparent color
>
> ...
>
> transparent_color [is] A defined color to be displayed as transparent
>   in the image.